# Triangle Inequality Proof squared

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

I'm having trouble with a version of a triangle inequality proof and not too sure where to start. The proof in my textbook asks to prove:
$$(a+b)^2\le(\mid a \mid + \mid b \mid)^2 $$[image]

My own process:

Case 1: a=0 b>0

$a^2 + b^2 + 2ab =b^2 = \mid a^2 \mid +\mid b^2 \mid + 2*\mid a \mid \mid b \mid$

Case 2:
a>0 b<0

$a = \mid a \mid$

$-b = \mid b \mid$

$a^2 = \mid a \mid ^2$

$(b)^2 = \mid b \mid ^2$

$a^2 + b^2 +2ab <  \mid a^2 \mid +\mid b^2 \mid + 2*\mid a \mid \mid b \mid$

This inequality would simplify to

$b< \mid b \mid $

Which is true based off of the statements above

Case 3:

a>0 b>0

$a = \mid a \mid$

$b = \mid b \mid$

$a^2 = \mid a \mid ^2$

$(b)^2 = \mid b \mid ^2$

Therefore

$a^2 + b^2 + 2ab =b^2 = \mid a^2 \mid +\mid b^2 \mid + 2*\mid a \mid \mid b \mid$

Apologies in advance if the proof leaves out many steps, I am new to this and am trying to learn the aspects that make a proof valid and coherent.

Comment: Are $a$ and $b$ real numbers?  $(2+3)^2\color{red}>|2|^2+|3|^2$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. In order to get responses that suit your needs, please include **in the body of the question** your own thoughts, the effort made so far, and the specific difficulties that got you stuck. BTW, I didn't downvote.

Comment: I think you want $ | (a+b) | \le ( |a| + |b| ) $.  At least, I think that is a reasonable statement of the triangle inequality.  Note that it is typically in a vector space of some sort.

Comment: Hi sorry, I mistyped the question. I updated it to the correct one and left the original problem from the question in the picture.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>You are squaring the lengths of the sides of a triangle and attempting to get a similar result.</strike>

For a triangle with side lengths: 1, 1, 0.5, we get ${0.5}^2 = 0.25 \lt 1^2 + 1^2 = 2$

For a triangle with side lengths: 1, 1, 1.5, we get ${1.5}^2 = 2.25 \gt 1^2 + 1^2 = 2$

Result: squaring the lengths of the sides of a triangle does not have  the same properties as the triangle inequality.

#### Edit, for the updated question:

$$ (a+b)^2\le(\mid a \mid + \mid b \mid)^2 $$
$$ a^2 + 2ab + b^2 \le { \mid a \mid }^2 + 2 \mid a \mid \mid b \mid + { \mid b \mid }^2 $$
$$ a^2 + 2ab + b^2 \le a^2 + 2 \mid a \mid \mid b \mid + b^2 $$
$$ 2ab \le 2 \mid a \mid \mid b \mid $$
$$ ab \le \mid a \mid \mid b \mid $$
$$ ab \le \mid a b \mid $$

Comment: Sorry about that, I wasn't very careful when typing the question in. I updated it and put my attempt of the proof on there. I have a general sense on what to do, but am struggling to understand which steps are important in making the proof coherent

Answer (score 0):

$(a+b)^2 \le |a|^2+|b|^2 \iff a^2+b^2+2ab \le |a|^2+|b|^2 = a^2+b^2 \iff 2ab \le 0 \iff ab \le 0$. Therefore inequality is not true for all $a$ and $b$.

Did you mean $|a+b|^2 \le 2(|a|^2+|b|^2) $? Or maybe $|a+b| \le |a|+|b|$?

Comment: Apologies, I updated the question. I typed the original question wrong